# How can I check with scene I am using?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have all menu on one canvas. How can I check which scene I am using now? I try this code, but it always shows that index of the scene is 0.

```
 Scene currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene ();

 string sceneName = currentScene.name;

 int buildIndex = currentScene.buildIndex;
```

Answer (score -1):

To check what scene is currently open you can make use of the SceneManagement namespace provided by Unity. Using the SceneManager class you can retrieve the currently active scene in the game and store it into a temporary variable which you can then use to check either it's name or build index in a conditional. **If your active scene is"0" its return "0" for sure.** For example:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
 {
     void Start ()
     {
         // Create a temporary reference to the current scene.
         Scene currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene ();

         // Retrieve the name of this scene.
         string sceneName = currentScene.name;

         if (sceneName == "Example 1") 
         {
             // Do something...
         }
         else if (sceneName == "Example 2")
         {
             // Do something...
         }

         // Retrieve the index of the scene in the project's build settings.
         int buildIndex = currentScene.buildIndex;

         // Check the scene name as a conditional.
         switch (buildIndex)
         {
         case 0:
             // Do something...
             break;
         case 1:
             // Do something...
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

Here's the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html

Comment: credits from here https://answers.unity.com/questions/1173303/how-to-check-which-scene-is-loaded-and-write-if-co.html

Answer (score -1):

Here's mine to check what the current active scene you are using . Base on Unity Docs

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GetActiveSceneExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        Debug.Log("Active scene is '" + scene.name + "'.");
    }
}
```

This is the simplest way to determine which scene are you using .